# Equality of an increasing function to Cantor-Lebesgue function.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to solve this question -

If $f$ is any increasing function on $[0,1]$ which agrees with Cantor-Lebesgue function on $[0,1] \sim C$, where C is cantor set, show that f equals Cantor-Lebesgue function in $[0,1]$.

> I am able to show the equality for set $(0,1)$. But can't $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ take any value $\le 0$  and $\ge 1$ respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question must be incorrectly stated, if the only restriction on $f$ is that it's increasing and it agrees with a function on the complement of the Cantor set, then clearly there is nothing there to force $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ to be $0$ and $1$.  My guess is that $f$ is supposed to be a function from $[0,1]$ into itself.

Comment: the question is from Real Analysis - H.L. Royden 4th ed. I guess the question must be wrong.